# Writing desk/bureau slide arm repair

Tags: repair

I'm trying to repair an old writing desk and I can't work out how to get to the screws that attach the sliding wooden support for the writing desk. Any ideas? The metal slide on one side was broken so I've asked my dad to fix it (braze it) but now I can't work out how to actually attach the back bracket to the wooden runner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove the screws in place, you will need either a stubby screwdriver(short one) or an offset screwdriver( screwdriver bent like an 'L').  Both would be harder to use in that space, than if you could remove that section to the open.

Most stubbies are a little more than 2 to 3 inches high.  Offsets can be a little less than a inch.

Need to know the type of head of screws to match the right screwdriver, slot, philips, robertsons.

Might also be able to use a ratchet handle or wrench with a screwdriver bit